# How to sort a string array according to string length in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

I'm trying to sort string array in this way. But the first string of the array isn't printing correctly. How can I code it in a easy way? I need to use it for competitive programming. So, it would be great if the code is short.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s[] = {"midnight", "Coder", "comp", "Wedn", "Top", "at"};
    int n = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
    sort(s->begin(), s->end());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<s[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output Result: **dghiimnt Coder comp Wedn Top at**

Output Expected: **midnight Coder comp Wedn Top at**

Comment: `s->begin()` isn't doing what you think it does.

Comment: Use 'std::vector<std::string> strings', and 'std::sort(strings.begin(),strings.end());' And learn about [range based](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for loops on containers.  There is not need for this sizeof stuff in C++ (kind of legacy from "C")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++20 you would do it like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s[] = {"midnight", "Coder", "comp", "Wedn", "Top", "at"};

    std::ranges::sort(s, std::greater{}, &std::string::size);

    for (const auto &it : s)
        std::cout << it << " ";
}
```

- `std::greater{}` means larger elements should come first (as opposed to the default `std::less{}`).
- `&std::string::size` means we sort by the return value of `.size()`, as opposed to comparing the elements directly.

I've also fixed some style issues.

Answer (score 3):

One way(probably the simplest) is to use a lambda for this as shown below.

```
int main()
{
    string s[] = {"midnight", "Coder", "comp", "Wedn", "Top", "at"};
    int n = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
    //use lambda 
    sort(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
    {
        return a.size() > b.size();
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<s[i]<<" ";
    }
    
}
```

[working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KrsoeWETW)